# HTML5 contextmenu attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm following a tutorial to create a **HTML5 contextmenu**, and have so far got the following lines of code in my website:

```
<a id="logo" href="http://mywebsite.com"  contextmenu="download-logo">                  
    <img class="default-logo" alt="My Website" src="http://mywebsite.com/logox2-standard.png" />
    <img class="retina-logo" alt="My Website" src="http://mywebsite.com/logox2-retina.png" /> 

    <menu type="context" id="download-logo">
        <menu label="Looking For Our Logo?">
            <menuitem label="Download High Resolution (45KB)" icon="http://www.mywebsite.com/logo-icon.jpg" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.mywebsite.com/logo-retina.zip'"></menuitem>
            <menuitem label="Download Low Resolution (20KB)" icon="http://www.mywebsite.com/logo-icon.jpg" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.mywebsite.com/logo-standard.zip'"></menuitem>
        </menu>     
    </menu>
</a>
```

This works perfectly fine when viewing the website in Mozilla Firefox, which is currently the only browser that  supports it:

[HTML contextmenu Attribute (W3Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp).

However, there is a polyfill available that will add additional support in other web browsers:

[jQuery-contextMenu (GitHub)](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu).

How do I apply this polyfill to my current code above, once I've included the JavaScript file in to the `<head>` tag of my website?

Please keep in mind I'm not very familiar with JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: The have mantioned hot wo initialize the plugin in the usage section. Are you getting any bugs when you do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `menu` and `menuitem` elements were featured in the initial HTML5 Candidate Recommendation but [have since been removed](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/). Firefox should not be handling these elements any more and other browsers are correct to ignore them.

In fact, the entire context menus section which was present in the [20121217 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/interactive-elements.html#context-menus) has been removed. Within that particular draft they're marked alongside other removed elements such as `hgroup` and `command` as:

> The following features are at risk and may be removed due to lack of implementation.

So in short: you shouldn't use this at all as it's no longer featured in the specification. You should instead find alternative methods to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How do I apply this polyfill"! Infact, it is outright missleading. The polyfill creates a menu using js/css and doesn't integrate with the browser, so it is a perfectly valid implementation.

Comment: @Twifty I sort of get your point, but the thing is there's no need to use a polyfill if there is zero browser support.  You'd be better off writing your own library that uses the syntax that makes sense for your project rather than trying to polyfill a non-standard syntax that has been deprecated.