# How to use an image context menu on a non-image element?

Tags: css, html

I am working on an image-gallery and the navigation controls are intentionally overlapping the image element.  When a user right clicks over one of the navigation control objects, I want the right-click menu to mirror what the user would see if they had right clicked on the image element.  How can I do this? I know that custom contextmenu objects have been deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930942/1455292

When I right click over either `.nav-left` or `.nav-right`, I want the user to see `.photo`'s context menu.

Here is an example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/9u3ghpnv/

Example Markup:

```
<div class="gallery">
<img class="photo" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7707/circle2.svg" />
<button class="nav-left">L</button>
<button class="nav-right">R</button>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.gallery{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 360px;
}

.photo{
display: block;
width: 360px;
height: 360px;
background-color: red;
}

.nav-left, .nav-right{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
color: lime;
font-size: 48px;
transition: all 0.5s;
background: none;
border: none;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-left{
left: 0;
}

.nav-right{
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use an overflow menu that you can left-click and show up a single pane but different entries for each nav item.

Comment: Well the user will still be able to interact with the image by navigating to the direct version and downloading it through interface buttons that I have on the actual gallery, but I want them to see the image context menu when they right click since they might just do that intuitively and not know what the icons / buttons do.

Comment: Using right click in this day and age is not a good tactic. You want to leave that to the browser and the user.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have uploaded on the Fiddle is exactly what you have and you need the buttons to be click through so the user can actually get the context menu of the underlying image.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

But then those buttons don't serve any purpose now, do they? since they are un-clickable :/

So now you may have to use a mix of these tricks or just use a `popover` button and `JS` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out to get an idea of what I was talking about.

Notice the top left corner has an overflow menu.

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gallery">
    <img class="photo" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7707/circle2.svg" />
  <a href="#" id="overflow_menu" onclick="showMenuPanel(true)">
    <img src="http://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_overflow.png" />
  </a>  
  <div id="photo_menu" class="menu">
    <a href="#" onclick="showMenuPanel(false)">close menu</a>
    <p>Put a list of contextual items here</p>
  </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-container">
      <a href="#" class="nav-button left">&#9664;</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-button right">&#9654;</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS**

```
.gallery{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 360px;
}

.photo{
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: red;
}

.nav-bar-container {
  width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  top: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.nav-button{
  padding: 24px;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
.nav-button : link, visited {
  color: #eee;
}

.nav-button:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.menu {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 15;
}
.menu a:link, a:visited, p {
  color: #eee;
}

#overflow_menu { 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 0px;
}
#overflow_menu img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
#overflow_menu:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

**The JavaScript**

```
function showMenuPanel(bShow){
  photo_menu.style.display = bShow ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Link to live code in case it's still there: http://jsbin.com/riyowecaye

Comment: Right, I have one of those already, I just figured that users would right click and expect to get a regular context menu for an image.  It doesn't look like it is possible though so a menu will have to suffice.

Comment: Oh. I think I misunderstood you. When you say context menu you mean the native browser menu like this http://imgur.com/YHoSyAC?

Comment: Yep, exactly like that!